# Published google sheet doesn't refresh

Tags: google-sheets, embed, publish

I have published Google Sheet via 'Publish to the web' in Sheet and implemented it on my website with iframe:

```
 <div style="position:relative;width:100%; height:0px;left: 0; padding-bottom:56.25%;">

<iframe style="position:absolute; top:40px; width:100%; height:100%"
    src="Google_sheet_link">

</iframe> </div>
```

When I edit it -> it doesn't apply on the website (google sheets are  refreshing every 5 minutes automatically, but it doesn't apply anyway).

It works only when I change link manually for example from sheet-link.com/ to sheet-link.com.

Comment: Is your browser or host caching the page? When you visit the actual google document (as opposed to your embed of the document), do you see the updated content?

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing this problem for a couple of years. Then I discovered that one of the people i had shared the Sheet with was  leaving it open on there computer. If ANYONE has the the Google Sheet Doc open it will not update on the Published  version until a change is made by anyone until all are closed. Now that i have all my shares closing Docs when they are finished editing there are no more problems...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue intrinsic to Google Sheets. There is an open support request for it [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4836432?hl=en).

There may be a possible(!) work-around [here](https://medium.com/@steynviljoen/how-to-share-or-embed-a-google-sheets-chart-that-updates-instantly-no-need-to-wait-for-5-minutes-b6d325cd8598).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.